# Handling add/access elements within Nested Maps

Tags: c++

How to add and access keys / values to the mapofmaps?

```
typedef map<string, map<string,map<string,vector<double>>> > mapofmaps;
```

Need to add rows with key1+key2+key3 being unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapofmaps m;
m["key1"]["key2"]["key3"] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
```

Comment: need to access keys/values within a loop using iterators. How?. With nested maps it gets more complicated.